# Invalid null added to HTTP response JSON body when reading with ioutil in golang

Tags: json, rest, go

So this one is driving me insane. I'm not even sure if the title is 100% correct because I'm having some trouble to narrow the issue down to one specific part.

I have two applications that talk to each other via REST. One accepts the HTTP GET request from the other app, and answers with some JSON. For the HTTP router I use Gorilla/mux btw. So far so good.

My first application (let's call it `FooReader`), is calling my second application (let's call it `FooWriter`) via HTTP GET:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Set("uuid", "my uuid")
req.Header.Set("api_token", "my token")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

This works just fine. As you can see I'm sending some additional stuff in the header, that's why I'm not using `http.Get()`. (Is there a better way to do this?)

Now `FooWriter` receives that request and processes it:

```
...
var successJSON = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
w.Write([]byte(successJSON))
w.WriteHeader(200)

if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err); err != nil {
    ...
}
```

Back in `FooReader` I now receive the response from `FooWriter` and read it (I've added the Do() call again for clarity):

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

fmt.Println("response Code:", resp.StatusCode)

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(resp.Body, 1048576))
if err != nil {
    ...
}

fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
```

Now comes the weird part: When I print the response body like I do in the last line, there is an additional `null` added to the original JSON string:

```
response Code: 200
response Body: {"foo":"bar"}null
```

My guess is that there is some `nil` thrown in there before the JSON decoding, but I just can't find it.
Also I'm guessing that the issue has to be on the `FooReader` side, because I'm using the exact same code on `FooWriter` side on some other part of the application, which works fine.

Did I miss anything? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: try fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body[:])) instead of string(body)

Comment: It's the same result: `response Body: {"foo":"bar"}null`

Comment: May be if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err) is printing null when err is null

Comment: That's it! `err` is nil, so it encodes the actual JSON plus err. I'm just wondering how to do it correctly then?

Comment: Got it: So instead of adding the JSON payload to the `ResponseWriter` via `w.Write(myJsonStruct)`, I'm passing it now directly to Encode(), which then encodes it perfectly.

Comment: Glad that it worked :) I am adding it as answer

Comment: Just realised that I didn't say thanks: So thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)` is printing null when err is nil. Pass response to encode and make err part of it so only one json structure is printed.